# Error "Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor" is returned

Tags: java, junit, compiler-errors

after searching and finding no proper answer, i am raising it here.

I wrote the below simple class with a @Test and when i try to run i am getting "java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor" error. Can someone please help me in resolving this issue.

```
package Shopping.Tests;

import Shopping.Config.TestData;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.Test;

@Slf4j
public class TestScenario1 {

private final TestData testData;

public TestScenario1(TestData testData) {
    this.testData = testData;
}

@Test
public void sampleTest(){
    log.info(testData.getBaseURL());
}
}
```

Comment: No need to search. Just read the error message. A test class must have exactly one **public zero-argument** constructor. Does your class have a public zero-argument constructor? I see only one constructor, and it has more than zero argument.

Comment: The message says it all: your test must have exactly one constructor and that must not have parameters, i.e. instead of ` TestScenario1(TestData testData)` it has to be ` TestScenario1()`. Then look up on how to pass data to that test.

Answer (score 4):

This non-default constructor makes it impossible for the testing framework to create an instance of the class

```
public TestScenario1(TestData testData) {
```

You need a no-arg constructor:

```
public TestScenario1() { //or have no explicit constructor declared at all
```

Initializing test data is typically done in a method annotated with `@Before` (assuming junit is your test framework - see [@Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) and [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html))

```
public TestScenario1() {}
@Before
public void prepareTestData() {
    this.testData = fetchTestData()...//It can't be passed in as parameter.
}
```